# Picking the Order of Images in a Component (Div) (Drag-and-Drop jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-selectors

I have a problem. I have a div component where I'll drag multiple images. This part is working perfectly. But I am not able to read the order of these images played in the component. What happens, I can play any position in the image of the div component, however, like to read in order as they are, from left to right.

I believe it is possible, but the solution must be complicated. Some of his friends could help me in the routine javascript to read this? Or know any technique that can help me.

Thanks

The Page Code:
(all code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

.draggable { 
    width: 90px; 
    height: 80px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0; 
    font-size: .9em; 
}

.ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p { 
    margin: 0; 
}

.ui-widget-header-modified p {
    color:#99CC99;          
}

#snaptarget { 
    height: 300px; 
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var Cont = 0;
addComponent = function(strImg){
    if ($.trim(strImg) != '')
    {
        Cont = Cont + 1;
        $('#imgPrompt img').remove();
        $('#imgPrompt').prepend('<img id="' + strImg + '_Img' + Cont + '" src="' + strImg + '.gif" />');

        $('#' + strImg + '_Img' + Cont).draggable({ snap: true });
    }
}

 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
<div class="demo">

    <div id="snaptarget" class="ui-widget-header">
        <p>Estrutura do Caminhão:</p>
    </div>

    <div id="snaptarget" style="border:dotted;border-color:#000000;height:310px">

        <div style="float:left;width:15%">
            <center>
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Livre Roda Simples" onclick="addComponent('eixolivre_rodasimples');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Livre Roda Única" onclick="addComponent('eixolivre_rodaunica');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Simples Roda Dupla" onclick="addComponent('eixosimples_rodadupla');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Tracionado Rodado Duplo" onclick="addComponent('eixotracionado_rodadoduplo');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Tracionado Rodado Simples" onclick="addComponent('eixotracionado_rodadosimples');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Trator Roda Dupla" onclick="addComponent('eixotrator_rodadupla');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Trator Roda Simples" onclick="addComponent('eixotrator_rodasimples');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Eixo Trator Roda Única" onclick="addComponent('eixotrator_rodaunica');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Estepe Duplo" onclick="addComponent('estepe_duplo');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Estepe Simples" onclick="addComponent('estepe_simples');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Estepe Triplo" onclick="addComponent('estepe_triplo');"/><br />
                <input type="button" style="width:200px" value="Alongamento Eixo" onclick="addComponent('estruturaeixo_livre');"/><br />
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="imgPrompt" style="float:right;width:85%;height:310px;text-align:center">
            <!-- Adicionar as Imagens -->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you want to be able to iterate through images in the actual order that they appear in the DOM?  Well that's the order you get when you just find the elements with jQuery ...

Comment: @Pointy I would like to know the order of display. I believe that is not the same as the order of the document (created). Is possible?

Comment: Does the "drag/drop" code arrange them with CSS positioning so that they show up in different order than the DOM order? If that is true, then I do not know how to help.

Comment: @Pointy Is complicated! Even if I take the position, would be complicated then save and load. Already a few hours I'm trying to find a good solution. Just so you understand, I got to ride a route structure design.

Comment: Yes, I agree that that sounds complicated :-)  That particular kind of programming is not something I do very much, so I do not even know where to start!  Maybe you have to "search" for the `<img>` boxes by position, starting from the top-left of your container?  I am not good at that sort of thing.

Comment: @Pointy would not it be better if I split the parent div in several parts, and allow only one object for each of these parts? So, I have already ordered square, rather then just read. But we still do not know how to make a simple control, and split the div so that it is invisible.

Comment: Hmm ... Yes, maybe if your "drop" targets were like "cells", so that you could only have one image per cell, that would make it a LOT easier!

Comment: @Pointy But do you know if there any solution or command me facilitate these cells to create different sizes. Otherwise I have to make one for (javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to friend "tentonaxe" [jQuery forum] by the code to get the objects ordered by their position in the document. Then, with a few more implementations, could develop all the features desired for the screen.

In order to answer questions from other people, will be posting the code here. Just remembering that I was not I who developed it. Credits [Tentonaxe](http://www.tentonaxe.com/)

```
   getImageOrder = function(){
        var $imgArr = $('img').sort(function(a,b){
                var keyA = $(a).offset().left;
                var keyB = $(b).offset().left;
                if (keyA > keyB){ return 1; }
                if (keyA < keyB){ return -1; }
                return 0;
            })

        var finalArray = new Array();
        $imgArr.each(function(index){
            finalArray[index] = { id  : $(this).attr("id"), src : $(this).attr("src"), pX  : $(this).css("left"), pY  : $(this).css("top") }
        })

        return finalArray;
    }
```